# Disable the shadow on UIPopoverViewController's content view

Tags: ios, ios5

I'm creating a custom popover for a UIPopoverController by subclassing UIViewController to manage the content view and UIPopoverBackgroundView for a custom background. Everything works great, except the UIPopoverController is applying a shadow to the content view, making the content appear bordered with shadow. I can't seem to find which view's layer is shadowed. How can I disable this shadow? Has anyone else ran into this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As this is still standing months later, I'll close this by saying I implemented my own popup controller. It's a shame, though, one would think there would be a better way...